# w3wp versus mvsmon

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging

I'm trying to figure out the difference between w3wp and msvsmon. Both seem to be remote debugging tools that run on the web server, and we can attach to them via Visual Studio to help in debugging live applications. Is this correct ? If so what are the differences between them ? many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`w3wp` is the w3 (www) worker process. This is what *runs* the website. This will allow remote debugging of websites.

`msvsmon` is the remote debugger monitor, this is what actually allows remote debugging for all applications.